# How to improve accuracy of text search in beautifulsoup using regex, and/or filtering items from a list of "to be excluded text strings"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have built a basic scraper that iterates through a list of queries compiled using regex and returns a beautiful soup element I can then extract various depending elements from (parent tag, div class, links, etc.)

```
queries = ["Foo", "Dog", "Cat", "Bar"]
for query in queries:
    unfiltered_titles = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(query))
print(unfiltered_titles)
["Foo", "Brown Dog", "Free Cat", "Yellow Cat", "Old Bar", "Dark Bar", "Bar"]
```

So far, so good. I now have a list object called "unfiltered_titles" with decently relevant results. Going through these titles, however, I've noticed that some of my titles contain words I would like to exclude or filter out. Ideally, I could store these "negative" words or items in a list or dictionary, iterate through it for each query-scrape run, and filter or pop these out from my "unfiltered_titles" list.

```
#Example List of Words to exclude
negative_list = ["Brown", "Free", "Dark","Old",...]
#desired output:
filtered_list = ["Foo", "Cat", "Yellow Cat", "Bar"]
```

I've tried looking into this great regex article [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html), but before heading this way, I'm curious to know if:

- I can iterate through a list of negative lookaheads
- negative lookaheads can be coupled with a variable declared outside my loop, or in this case "query"
- If my filtered_list can keep beautifulsoup properties that are needed in later functions/computations.
- this will increase the request calls sent through beautifulsoup to the website
- (OR) using complex regex on each query in my loop will drastically slow down my runs.

Especially for the last points, I wonder if it would be more reasonable to treat my results stored in a csv, and filter out rows for which titles include items from my negative_list using regex or not.

How would you couple this problem in python? Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For such simple case, you don't need regex at all. To create `unfiltered_list`, you can do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''
<div>Foo</div> <div>Brown Dog</div> <div>Free Cat</div> <div>Yellow Cat</div> <div>Old Bar</div> <div>Dark Bar</div> <div>Bar</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

queries = ["Foo", "Dog", "Cat", "Bar"]

unfiltered_titles = [tag.parent for tag in soup.find_all(text=lambda t: any(w in queries for w in t.split()))]
print(unfiltered_titles)
```

Prints:

```
[<div>Foo</div>, <div>Brown Dog</div>, <div>Free Cat</div>, <div>Yellow Cat</div>, <div>Old Bar</div>, <div>Dark Bar</div>, <div>Bar</div>]
```

Notice, I used `tag.parent` to keep BeautifulSoup tags in the list (this will help further navigating the code).

To filter the items further, you can do:

```
negative_set = {"Brown", "Free", "Dark","Old"}   # <-- keep the items in the set for speed


filtered_list = [tag for tag in unfiltered_titles if all(w not in negative_set for w in tag.text.split())]
print(filtered_list)
```

Prints:

```
[<div>Foo</div>, <div>Yellow Cat</div>, <div>Bar</div>]
```

Comment: Andrej! Thank you so much. This is making it so much easier, especially using and() and any() in the list comprehensions. This said, I've been trying to import this chunk back in my script, but noticed that I need my filtered_list to be of class bs4.element.ResultSet and not list. The tag is confusing me here

Comment: I'm trying to nest the second lambda into the first...atm

Comment: @LucaVJ every item in `unfiltered_titles` is of type `bs4.Tag` so you can use `.find` or `.select` on them like in `soup`

Comment: I've managed it! Just needed to list.remove(negative) from Resultset! :)

Comment: Ah! That required more substantial changes to other chunks of my code that are not as beautiful :) But, this helps a lot, having the bs4.Tag higher up accessible! Thank you so much, I've learned a lot!